# UICollectionView ScrollTo Crashing

Tags: swift, uiview, swift3, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

I am attempting to have my UICollectionView in my custom UIView, be able to scroll to a page when a button is pressed in the main VC. Unfortunately everytime I call the method to do it in the MainVC, it crashes, @ to scrollToItem .

here is my MainVC.

```
let mainView = MainViewsHome()
```

In the ViewWillAppear:

```
/** Setting up the bottom half **/
        mainView.frame = CGRect(x:self.view.frame.width * 0, y:self.view.frame.height / 6.2, width:self.view.frame.width,height:self.view.frame.height / 1.1925)
        mainView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        self.view.addSubview(mainView)
```

&& My custom UIView

```
class MainViewsHome: UIView, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    var cellId = "Cell"

    var collectionView : UICollectionView!


     override init(frame: CGRect) {

        super.init(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height / 1.3))

        /**Creation of the View **/
        let flowLayout : UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        flowLayout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
        flowLayout.scrollDirection = .horizontal

        let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: CGRect(x:self.frame.width * 0,y:self.frame.height * 0,width:self.frame.width,height: self.frame.height), collectionViewLayout: flowLayout)
        collectionView.register(uploadGenreSelectionCVC.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)
        collectionView.isPagingEnabled = true
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.purple

        self.addSubview(collectionView)

    }


    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func moveToPage() {
     print("we are moving to page")

        self.collectionView.scrollToItem(at: 2 as IndexPath, at: UICollectionViewScrollPosition.right, animated: true)

    }
```

&& Then in my MainVC I am calling: `mainView.moveToPage()` Where am I going wrong with my understanding?

Comment: can you please post the crash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is with `2 as IndexPath`, [`IndexPath`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/indexpath) is not `Integer` so you need to make the object of `IndexPath` using its init `init(item:section:)`. and after that scroll `collectionView` to specific item this way.

```
func moveToPage() {
    let indexPath = IndexPath(item: 2, section: 0) //Change section from 0 to other if you are having multiple sections
    self.collectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .right, animated: true)
}
```

**Note:** `CollectionView's` items start at `0` index so if you want to scroll to 2nd item then make `indexPath` using `IndexPath(item: 1, section: 0)` because `2nd` will scroll at 3rd cell of `collectionView`.

Comment: The crashing stopped, but the cell does not move to it? Do I need to share information through a delegate?

Comment: @AndrewS Can you show some more detail also share some screen shot of running screen how it looks like

Comment: https://paste.ee/p/6YwOr  ||  https://paste.ee/p/Nlzt0 these are the two classes & here is an image of what it looks like on my screen http://imgur.com/a/w0BE0, the 4 blue boxes at the top are the tab bar, & the blue screen is the custom pages that I have,

Comment: I have also opened up another thread here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44457157/nothing-occurring-with-scrolltoitem-in-uicollectionview

Comment: Thank you so much, didn't even catch that!

Comment: @AndrewS Welcome mate :)